# Cancel a push segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, segue

I've got an app that uses a UINavigationBarController and I push to all ViewControllers, but in one ViewController I want the user to pick a value in a PickerView, if they don't pick anything then when they click on the Next button (Which is a push segue to next viewcontroller) I want them to get an alert (which is already fixed), but also to cancel the segue so it doesn't move to the next viewcontroller.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to change the uibutton action programmatically. If a date has not been picked, the buton triggers an alert. When the user selects a date, change the action of the "next" button to perform a segue with identifier.

Comment: I thought about the same way 1min ago :) +1

Comment: Okay, but this would remove the navigationbaritem in storyboard, will it affect my App in any way other than display in xcode?